# Can the user see URL called from Android app?

Tags: android, security, url, encryption, httpclient

If I have standard URL call in my **Android** app code

```
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

                String url = "http://www.google.com";

                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpResponse response = null;
                String result = "";
                try {
                    response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
                    BufferedReader reader = null;

                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                    String line = null;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                         result += line;
                    }
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

My question is - can the user see the URL called here (in this example: **www.google.com**) in some kind of log or something? I assume that the user with rooted phone could see that information?

Is there a way to **hide it/encrypt** it?

**EDIT:** Or, is there a way to check (PHP maybe?) if the user is coming to my website/URL from mobile phone (my application) or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with a non-rooted phone, a user could run a packet sniffer on their gateway to see where they're connecting.

To "hide" the URL you could proxy its data through your own server, and provide the app with a URL to that server instead.

**Edit:** Re. your edit, you can check the browser's [user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent), but there's no foolproof way to be certain that a user is connecting from your app (it boils down to a DRM problem).

Comment: I need to send some data, so the SSL + POST data is the only way? And of course on the other side (.php side) if the POST auth key doesn't match - reject everything. So if the user knows the URL he couldn't use it.

Comment: There's nothing to stop a sufficiently motivated attacker from extracting the key and accessing the URL masquerading as your app.

Comment: so...ProGuard + SSL (POST) should be enough? Is there something stronger than this combination?

Comment: That should be perfectly adequate to prevent regular users from accessing your URL without your app; though, as above, anyone with the requisite skill will manage it with enough motivation.